# Describe how to find a basis $\beta$ for $R^n$ and a basis $C$ for $R^m$

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, diagonalization

Let $T : R^n → R^m$ be a linear transformation. Describe how to find a basis
$\beta$

for $R^n$ and a basis $C$ for $R^m$ such that matrix for $T$ relative to $\beta$ and $C$ is an

diagonal matrix $P$ of size $m × n$.

Comment: In standard terminology a diagonal matrix has to be square; I have no idea what a "diagonal" $m\times n$ matrix might be.

Answer (score 1):

This is the well known [canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_equivalence#Canonical_form) of a matrix.

Take $\{\beta_{k+1}, \dots, \beta_n\}$ (where $0\le k \le n$) as a basis of the kernel of $T$. Then according to the rank-nullity theorem, the dimension of the image of $T$ is $k$. Take $\{\beta_1, \dots, \beta_{k}\}$ such that $$\{C_1=T(\beta_1), \dots, C_{k} = T(\beta_{k})\}$$ is a basis of the image of $T$. Complete $\{C_1, \dots , C_{k}\}$ into a basis $\{C_1, \dots C_m\}$ of $\mathbb R^m$.

The two basis are the one you're looking for.